# How can I automatically create an image "key" with group photo silhouettes tagged with people's names?

Tags: software, metadata

From a group photo, I would like to create an image that identify each person with their names.
My first idea was to create a silhouette image from the original one, put a number over each face, and present a list of number-name. I could do that using GIMP, for example.

Is there any more intelligent way of doing so?

Windows Photo Gallery, for example, has a tool for tagging people. Is it possible to produce a new image with tag information from the original one?

Comment: Don't know the answer, but I hope someone does. It would be a useful tool. I'd bet good money that most intelligence agencies have this. The first step would be to identify all the people and a number of apps have tools for that. KPhotoAlbum on Linux recently added automatic face recognition and tagging. The problem is that systems like this probably don't save the coordinates where each match occurred, so there would be no direct way of knowing where to graphically tag/annotate the image.

Comment: @Joe, face recognition would be nice but I would be happy to have a tool to create group photo silhouettes tagged with people's names even if I had to enter the names manually.

Comment: I asked on the KPA list. Here are a couple of comments which indicate how you might proceed. Basically, KPA already has the infrastructure to mark people (or whatever you 
want). This has even be added before the face management, by the positionable 
tags. You can mark areas on images and add a tag to them. So ... we already do 
have this functionality! Cont...

Comment: Second comment: Just as a quick idea this could probably be implemented as an independent python script.
The KPhotoalbum python library (although being quite slow) can parse all relevant data from the database file, which you could then use in a python program to generate the segment-images.

Comment: I guess we can split the question (and answers) in two cases: it would be good to have the automatic face recognition included in the answer (case 1), but also if we manually select the faces and manually tag them with names (case 2), it would still be useful to 'automate' just the last part: creating a printout with call-outs, maybe with the silhouette and numbers method, or with arrows

Comment: I would look into DigiKam, creating a Template for the "Print Creator". But I would't know how.

Answer (score 1):

If you're prepared to do some of your own development then you could maybe start with http://www.face-rec.org/.